# What's the difference between these 3 ISO files? Are they the same file?

Tags: texlive, ctan, texlive-2020

[image]

texlive.iso, texlive2021-20210325.iso, and texlive2021.iso. They seem to be of the same file size. Are they the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the [official website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html) to the nearest [CTAN mirror](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/Images/) you can read in the `README.md` file the following:

> ### TeX Live ISO Images
>
> This directory contains the ISO image for the official TeX Live
> release; md5 and sha512 checksums are provided, and the sha checksum
> is GPG-signed.  **The generic names (texliveYYYY.iso and texlive.iso)
> are symlinks to the dated release .iso.**
>
> The TeX Live web pages https://tug.org/texlive/ have information on:
>
> - ways to acquire the distribution https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html,
> - quick installation https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html,
> - documentation https://tug.org/texlive/doc.html,
> - reporting bugs and known issues https://tug.org/texlive/bugs.html, and more.
>
> Instead of dealing with this giant image, for typical use we recommend
> the small installer package(s) at
> https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html.
>
> If you have problems with installation or running TeX after
> installation, please check your environment variables: settings,
> including PATH, that end up referencing previously-installed TeX
> systems (TeX Live or otherwise), can cause trouble, especially on
> Windows.
>
> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

**So the `iso` files are identical.**

[image]